# How to save a result of any command into a variable?

Tags: bash, zsh, variable, stdout

Let's take this command

```
sudo doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p '$$!!!555;###..>^$$'
```

How can redirect its output into a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You simply set the variable name to the value of the executed command using a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
$ myVar=$(command-here)
```

or, using the deprecated syntax with backticks (which is somewhat problematic to use with e.g. nested substitutions):

```
$ myVar=`command-here`
```

Comment: will that work for any command? Won't a pipe be more flexible way?

Comment: @kesha933, pipes send the output of a command to the input of another, that's a different thing from assigning it to a variable or using on a command line